# How do I insert an array of hash maps into Redis? (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, database, node.js, redis

I'm using the Node.js module node_redis:

```
var data = [ {'name':'matt', 'id':'333' } , {'name':'Jessica','id':'492'} ] ;

//Initialize Redis
var redis = require('redis'),
rclient = redis.createClient(settings.redis.port, settings.redis.host,{pass:settings.redis.password});
rclient.auth(settings.redis.password, function(){});
rclient.on("error", function (err) {});


//OK, insert the data into redis
rclient.set("mykey", data);
```

When I do `set`, I get an error, why?

```
{ stack: [Getter/Setter],
  arguments: undefined,
  type: undefined,
  message: 'ERR wrong number of arguments for \'set\' command' }
Error: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'set' command
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `set` method expects a string as the second argument.

You could stringify your `data` variable, i.e.

```
rclient.set("mykey", JSON.stringify(data))
```

Answer (score 4):

- You could encode it to JSON(`JSON.stringify`) and then insert it in redis. To decode you then use `JSON.parse`
- [Redback](https://github.com/chriso/redback) has some nice abstractions on top of node_redis. [Hash](https://github.com/chriso/redback/blob/master/test/hash.test.js) might be what you are looking for?